# How can i force the user to click the notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification

Is there any way to make the user not able to cancel a notification? Only in one case 
if he taps it? If so, how?

My notification flags are here:

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 0, notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
```

by

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

after it'll be "ongoing" you'll need to handle click on it and use [NotificationManager.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int)) to remove it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to make a unique id for each notification (should i use shared preference) 
and how can i handle click ??

Comment: @MohhamedNabil please see training [Building a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)